# View attachments inline in html

Tags: html, web, xss

This is a question related to an internal web site with a small user base. It is used for threaded conversations between users (like a forum), but it is all custom made and contains some business logic. Users are allowed to upload attachments. And other users see a link to these attachments in the view an can download using that link.

I want to add a new feature to display images inline, instead of showing a link. I thought about sending an image tag with source attribute set to the location of the attachment.

My problem is, this is open for XSS attacks. A user might upload a javascript file that has a png extension, and image tag will execute the javascript on resource loading.

If relevant, backend is running a python based web server and front end is mostly plain html/javascript.

What would be a correct method to prevent attacks on this system?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to use the [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and follow their rules:

> - RULE #0 - Never Insert Untrusted Data Except in Allowed Locations
> - RULE #1 - HTML Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Element Content
> - RULE #2 - Attribute Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Common Attributes
> - RULE #3 - JavaScript Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into JavaScript Data Values
>
>   - RULE #3.1 - HTML escape JSON values in an HTML context and read the data with JSON.parse
> - RULE #4 - CSS Escape And Strictly Validate Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Style Property Values
> - RULE #5 - URL Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML URL Parameter Values
> - RULE #6 - Sanitize HTML Markup with a Library Designed for the Job
> - RULE #7 - Prevent DOM-based XSS
> - Bonus Rule #1: Use HTTPOnly cookie flag
> - Bonus Rule #2: Implement Content Security Policy
> - Bonus Rule #3: Use an Auto-Escaping Template System
> - Bonus Rule #4: Use the X-XSS-Protection Response Header